# Error while connecting jmx on Production

Tags: java, jmx

For some reason i'm not able to connect java pid on production server using VisualVM.

I have pass the jvm parameter in setenv.sh file:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \ 
            -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999\ 
             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false\ 
             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \ 
            -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.2"
```

and put this file into $ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/ directory.
and also for authentication purpose both jmxremote.password and jmxremote.access file put into "/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/" directory.

```
File permissions :

**$sudo chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/jmxremote.*** is ensuring that both file owned by tomcat7

**$ sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/jmxremote.*** //  access right for tomcat7
```

$ sudo cat jmxremote.password

```
admin alonegk
```

$ sudo cat jmxremote.access

```
admin readwrite
```

The Same thing running fine while i did it on dev server as well as my localhost.

*Thanks in anticipation.*

Comment: you try to connect from the outside? Did you check for firewalls? Can you access the port with telnet or the like?

Comment: You have set authentication to false, so username and password is not needed. Also, try with just "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" (No explicit true value assigned to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the following :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \ 
            -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999\ 
             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false\ 
             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \ 
            -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.2"
```

Since the authentication is set to false, username and password does not have any significance here.

In case you want to use username and password, the following two strings should be appended :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<PATH>/jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=<PATH>/jmxremote.access
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer